# SystemObjectDisposedException in unit test for moq object used in multiple places

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have mocked an object as below in my test code-

```
storageManager
    .Setup(m => m.GetFileStreamAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(stream_));
BulkExcelProcessorCommandHandler handler = new BulkExcelProcessorCommandHandler(storageManager)
```

It takes in a string and returns Stream of data.

```
public async Task<Stream> GetFileStreamAsync(string fileName)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(fileName)));
}
```

This is used as 2 places in my code -

```
 public BulkExcelProcessorCommandHandler(IAzureStorageService storageManager)
{
  _storageManager= storageManager;
}

public async Task<bool> Handle(BulkExcelProcessorCommand request)
 {
    using var file = await _storageManager.GetFileStreamAsync(fileUpload.FileContent);
   await SaveReportWithResponse(fileUpload.FileContent)
 }

private async Task SaveReportWithResponse(fileUpload.FileContent)
{
 var filestream = await _storageManager.GetFileStreamAsync(fileUpload.FileContent);
}
```

This first instance where it is used(`Handle()`) I see it working fine. However the one in `SaveReportWithResponse()` throws an exception `SystemObjectDisposedException`

I understand that this might be because the object is disposed, but how do I make sure that the object remains intact for the entire test. I have tried multiple solution from stackoverflow  removing the `using` part in the `Handle()` or using `Returns(() => Task.FromResult(stream_))` but nothing worked.

Comment: I'm guessing your unit test, or your unit under test, disposes the stream?

Comment: No, I don't see this happening in my unit test. @canton7. I am mocking and calling the handler that is it in the test.

Comment: Well *something* is disposing that stream, and it isn't in the code you've shown so far

Comment: Please share a [mre].

Comment: @GuruStron updated the code in the above question as mentioned

Comment: Your `using var file` will dispose the stream, of course...

Comment: I had tried removing that @canton7

Comment: Can you please provide definition of stream_

Comment: This still is not a [mre]. What is `stream_`? Do you access it after `Handle` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already tried deleting using and it didn't work,
Can you please try mock it multiple times like below:

```
storageManager.SetupSequence(_ => _.GetFileStreamAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
.Returns(() => Task.FromResult(stream_));  //Returned in the first call
.Returns(() => Task.FromResult(stream_)); //Returned in the second call
```

Comment: This didn't work, I still see the similar issue @mert akkanat

Comment: Can you please try with add "using" to  var filestream = await _storageManager.GetFileStreamAsync(fileUpload.FileContent); this will create a new instance and avoid conflicts. If not works please try combine my previous answer and this one.

Comment: It worked. I added using along with the above setupsequence @mert Akkanat